# Value and simplify

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I want to find the value and simplify square root 36 ?

Square root of 36 is 6 
But I would know how to find the value and simplify it .

Answer (score 3):

You have found the value, and I don't know a simpler form than $6$.

Comment: Try and Error method is enough !!!.

Comment: He means to ask how he would know that $\sqrt {36}=6$.

Comment: There is a Wikipedia article on methods of calculating square roots

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{36}=|6|=6.$

In general, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$

Answer (score 2):

To find the square root of $37$ (say) involves a fair bit of calculation, and you will never get a numerically exact answer. But the situation is much different for $36$. For a rigorous proof that $\sqrt{36}=6$, all you need to do is (1) observe that $6^2=36$ and (2) note that $6$ is positive. Generally, a perfectly legitimate way to solve a mathematical problem is simply to guess the answer, if you are lucky enough to do so, *and then verify that your guess is correct*.